# How can I insert an echo date("Y"); into a variable?

Tags: php, variables, date, echo

I'm trying to get a PHP variable to return ordinary HTML code, as well as the current year (expressed using `echo date("Y");`). Here's my current syntax:
`$myvar = "Lorem ipsum dolor sin amet " echo date("Y") " foo bar";`
I get an error saying 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /path/to/my/document on line 28`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, don't "echo" it - as echo writes to the HTTP response immediately. Instead, concat (keyword, look it up) it - the result of the `date("Y")` expression - with the string literals..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$myvar = "Lorem ipsum dolor sin amet " . date("Y") . " foo bar";
```

Answer (score 3):

you're missing the correct concatenation syntax, needs to be,

```
$myvar = "Lorem ipsum dolor sin amet " . date("Y") . " foo bar";
```

`echo` is a command used to print/display the value in a variable.

```
 echo $myvar; //will display "Lorem ipsum dolor sin amet 2012 foo bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
$date = date("Y");
echo"lorem ipsum dolor sin amet $date";
```

Keep it simple!